# Why does my string not pass the regex?

Tags: javascript, regex

This string(`kwordSyntaxSearch`) should pass the condition:

```
( sdf sdf )
cout<<"for you";

return 0; 
}
```

Here is my condition:

```
   /^\s*\([\s\S]*\)\s*[^\{][\s\S]*;\s*(if|else|else if|for|while|do|switch|\}|return)[\s\S]*$ /.test(kwordSyntaxSearch)
```

It doesnt want to pass the cond, what did i miss?

Comment: No.... no it is not...

Comment: Is the code the content of the string? Where/what is `kwordSyntaxSearch`?

Comment: `[\s\S]`? Why not `.`?

Comment: @Dan `.` doesn't match line breaks. and JS doesn't have an `s` modifier.

Comment: It does in single line mode, whereas `[\s\S]` is utterly unreadable.

Comment: @Dan as I said, there is no singleline mode in JS. the shortest you can do in JS is `[^]`.

Comment: yeah but you edited that in and I didn't see it until I commented.

Comment: @Dan oh right, nevermind.

Comment: Would there be some reason for `[\s\S]` over multi-line mode

Comment: @Keikoku it's called singleline mode and (see the above comments), it doesn't exist in JS.

Comment: I mean, why not just set the `m` flag

Comment: @Keikoku the `m` flag has nothing to do with `.` or `[\s\S]`. multiline mode only changes where `^` and `$` match (in all flavors except Ruby).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're requiring a space after the end of the string. Remove that space:

```
/^\s*\([\s\S]*\)\s*[^\{][\s\S]*;\s*(if|else|else if|for|while|do|switch|\}|return)[\s\S]*$/
```

Note that you can shorten the `[\s\S]` to `[^]` (a character class that matches every character "except no character"):

```
/^\s*\([^]*\)\s*[^\{][^]*;\s*(if|else|else if|for|while|do|switch|\}|return)[^]*$/
```